# MS Access Parsing Nested Arrays using VBA and JSON

Tags: json, vba, api, ms-access, nested

Have written code to call API using VBA from MS Access, but having issues extracting nested data. Am able to retrieve data from Items set, but also want to retrieve data from Attributes set where SetName=DG (in the below example there is only 1 AttributeSet, but could be more). Have followed some of the other similar posts, but just not working.
Returned Data:

```
{"Pagination":
{"NumberOfItems":1,
"PageSize":200,
"PageNumber":1,
"NumberOfPages":1},
"Items":[
{"ProductCode":"TEST",
"ProductDescription":"TEST",
"UnitOfMeasure":
{"Guid":"7e420466-4ced-48df-bb41-1693fe34a32c",
"Name":"EA",
"Obsolete":false},
"NeverDiminishing":false,
"ImageUrl":null,
"SellPriceTier1":
{"Name":"Sell Price Tier 1",
"Value":null},
"SellPriceTier2":
{"Name":"Sell Price Tier 2",
"Value":null},
"Supplier":null,
"AttributeSet":
{"Guid":"c3bd26c9-424a-4786-adbe-7c5a98b8f422",
"SetName":"DG",
"Type":"Product",
"Attributes":[
{"Guid":"6164f12b-2cb9-491c-b932-e6fb050579df",
"Name":"UN",
"Value":"1993",
"IsRequired":false},
{"Guid":"aa13f1dd-2174-4993-b80d-22bf4f4f27da",
"Name":"Technical Name",
"Value":"2K REDUCED",
"IsRequired":false},
{"Guid":"664fbcd6-83be-4afc-b812-22c97ae38949",
"Name":"Flash Point",
"Value":"30",
"IsRequired":false},
{"Guid":"3bc41b7c-bd14-44f6-a6b0-72d1ba84adbb",
"Name":"Pack Group",
"Value":"III",
"IsRequired":false}]},
"IsSellable":true,
"AlternateUnitsOfMeasure":[
{"Guid":"d42f5682-02b3-43fa-a848-46e6023c3b9e",
"Name":"LT",
"ConversionRate":1.0000,
"ForPurchases":true}],
"LastModifiedOn":"\/Date(1674949964652)\/"}
]
}
```

Code:

```
Dim key_id, secret_key, URL As String
Dim strJson As String
Dim req As New XMLHTTP60
Dim strModule As String
Dim strFilter As String
Dim rs, rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim JsonText As Object
Dim Item As Object
Dim attset As Object
Dim att As Object
key_id = "API ID"
secret_key = "API key"
URL = "https://api.unleashedsoftware.com/"
strModule = "Products?"
strFilter = "productCode=TEST&includeAttributes=True"
strJson = URL + strModule + strFilter

req.Open "GET", strJson, False
req.setRequestHeader "api-auth-id", key_id
req.setRequestHeader "api-auth-signature", Base64HMAC("SHA256", strFilter, secret_key)
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
req.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
req.sEnd

Set JsonText = JsonConverter.ParseJson(req.responseText)

For Each Item In JsonText("Items")
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("aProduct")
With rs
    .AddNew
    !prodcode = Item("ProductCode")
    !proddesc = Item("ProdutDescription")
    .Update
End With

    For Each att In Item("Attributes")
        'get Attribute Value
        Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("aProdDGAttribute")
        With rs1
            .AddNew
            !Name = att("Name")
            !Value= att("Value")
            .Update
        End With
    Next att

Next Item

MsgBox "done"
```

locals window screenshot:
[image: locals window screenshot]

Comment: "Not working" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?

Comment: Items appears to be within pagination, so yeah, that wouldn't work. Inspect the result of `JsonText` to get a sense of how it's structured

Comment: @June7, any code i try for the 2nd For loop fails, usually with an object not found error, so just wanting the correct way to handle. Not an expert on this, but previous work has worked with structure of For Each att In Item("Attributes"), although in this case the attributes are another level down.

Comment: @Erik A - how best to see how 'JsonText' is structured?

Comment: By inspecting it through the locals window. Set a break point after it's set.

Comment: @Eric A - added screenshot of local windows result, not exactly sure what this means?

Comment: It indicates that item, attset, att objects are not set to anything, they are Nothing.

Comment: @June7, yes they are, but at that point should they be, this is at the point of parsing?

Comment: Code edited for clarification. Wanting to add Products to a table (aProduct) and Attributes relating to each to Product to a separate table (aProdDGAttribute). Where i am trying to get to is the right For...Next code to access the Attributes from the parsed data.

Comment: How are you relating these tables? With autonumber PK and number FK? Do you need to grab the new product PK to save with related attribute records?

Comment: June7 - yes i will be, i've left some code out, as that is not the issue, the issue is getting the correct code to access the Attributes

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994854/vba-json-parse-nested-json. I tested your JSON text in online parser analyzer and it says there are errors in structure - http://json.parser.online.fr/. This might take me days to figure out how to use JSON library. Otherwise, I would process as a regular text file.

Comment: June7 - edited JSON text, now correct, and no errors in online parser (had trimmed down text before posting as irrelevant to question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this which works for the given sample showing only one AttributeSet:

```
Dim First As Variant, Second As Variant
Dim items As Object, atts As Object

Set items = jSon("Items")
For Each First In items
    Debug.Print First("ProductCode")
    Debug.Print First("ProductDescription")
    Debug.Print First("AttributeSet")("SetName")
    Set atts = First("AttributeSet")("Attributes")
    For Each Second In atts
        Debug.Print Second("Name")
        Debug.Print Second("Value")
    Next
Next
```

Guidance from [Parse JSON objects and collection using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70016018/parse-json-objects-and-collection-using-vba)